# How can we migrate only all the permissions of selected files and folders from OneDrive to SharePoint Online by PowerShell?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

We have migrated all the selected file and folder from oneDrive by a internal tool, now, all the permission of selected files and folders, need to migrate to SharePoint Online by powershell script. Can it be possible?

Answer (score 0):

Permission / Inheritance is not something we can migrate separated from objects.

In this scenario, you can only set permissions to the files and folders using PowerShell and the permission needs to be specify manually.

Here are some links with samples for your reference:

[Use PowerShell to Set Permissions on All SharePoint Libraries, Folders and Files.](https://www.c5insight.com/Resources/Blog/tabid/148/entryid/729/use-powershell-to-set-permissions-on-all-sharepoint-libraries-folders-and-files.aspx)

[SharePoint Online: Set Folder Permissions using PowerShell.](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2016/09/sharepoint-online-set-folder-permissions-powershell.html)